# org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to s3 asynchronously using my Java Api, but in async thread the i/o stream is getting closed the request is completed

here is my code

Controller class

```
@PUT
   // @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream , @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail ) throws IOException {
        String key  = "media/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
        String s3MediaUrl =   S3Helper.IMG_BUCKET_NAME + key;
        fileUploadService.uploadFile(uploadedInputStream,fileDetail);

        return s3MediaUrl;
    }
```

FileUpliadSerivce Class

```
public void uploadFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws OustMeException, IOException {
        
Thread newThread = new Thread(() -> {
      byte[] bytes;
            try {
                bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedInputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            String fileName = fileDetail.getFileName();
            String filePath = "/tmp/" + fileName;
            File file = new File(filePath);
            try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(file.toPath())) {
                out.write(bytes);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("exception occurred while writing file to memory. Exception : {}", e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }
            String key = "course/media/image/" + fileName;
            S3Helper.getInstance().upload(S3Helper.IMG_BUCKET_NAME, key, filePath);
            file.delete();
    
});
 newThread.start();
    }
```

getting this exception on upload :

```
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.jvnet.mimepull.WeakDataFile.read(WeakDataFile.java:112)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataFile.read(DataFile.java:77)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.jvnet.mimepull.FileData.read(FileData.java:69)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream.fetch(DataHead.java:265)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream.read(DataHead.java:219)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2146)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:721)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at com.oustme.data.service.impl.FileUploadService.lambda$uploadFile$0(FileUploadService.java:32)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-07-21 12:15:40 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:377)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:436)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     at org.jvnet.mimepull.WeakDataFile.read(WeakDataFile.java:110)
2023-07-21 12:15:40     ... 14 more
```

is there any configuration changes needed to be done to keep the stream alive?

Comment: You don't need a configuration change, you need to fix your code. The stream is *always* going to be closed when the `@PUT` method returns. You must have read the stream before that happens, no way around it.